UWP, LibVLCSharp, MediaPlayerElement
I use the LibVLCSharp library and MediaPlayerElement by this library. On the GitLab of this library I found the sample on LibVLCSharp about how can I do the Chromecast, but I need to do the casting on another device such as TV.
The default Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement can cast stream to TV by using CastingDevicePicker Microsoft Documentation
I don't understand, How can I do the casting to TV by using LibVLCSharp media player?
I use the Media Player of LibVLCSharp instead of Windows.Ui.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement because it doesn't play the streams correctly.
